# Disable Option Values Opencart 2.1

Tags: javascript, php, html, opencart, opencart2.x

Is it possible to make some feature like Disable option values for all the products?
For example Some of my product have Red, Yellow, Green colors in options. When I dont have Red color, I need to edit all the products and delete Red color option.

Now Im thinking how to make this feature. So Id like to disable option values in Option page
Maybe you have some thoughts or ready made? Please help me

Here is code for option controller I have right now

```
public function index() {
    $this->language->load('catalog/option');

    $this->document->setTitle($this->language->get('heading_title'));

    $this->load->model('catalog/option');

    $this->getList();
}

public function add() {
    $this->language->load('catalog/option');

    $this->document->setTitle($this->language->get('heading_title'));

    $this->load->model('catalog/option');

    if (($this->request->server['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') && $this->validateForm()) {
        $this->model_catalog_option->addOption($this->request->post);

        $this->session->data['success'] = $this->language->get('text_success');

        $url = '';

        if (isset($this->request->get['sort'])) {
            $url .= '&sort=' . $this->request->get['sort'];
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['order'])) {
            $url .= '&order=' . $this->request->get['order'];
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['page'])) {
            $url .= '&page=' . $this->request->get['page'];
        }

        $this->response->redirect($this->url->link('catalog/option', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'] . $url, 'SSL'));
    }

    $this->getForm();
}

public function edit() {
    $this->language->load('catalog/option');

    $this->document->setTitle($this->language->get('heading_title'));

    $this->load->model('catalog/option');

    if (($this->request->server['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') && $this->validateForm()) {
        $this->model_catalog_option->editOption($this->request->get['option_id'], $this->request->post);

        $this->session->data['success'] = $this->language->get('text_success');

        $url = '';

        if (isset($this->request->get['sort'])) {
            $url .= '&sort=' . $this->request->get['sort'];
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['order'])) {
            $url .= '&order=' . $this->request->get['order'];
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['page'])) {
            $url .= '&page=' . $this->request->get['page'];
        }

        $this->response->redirect($this->url->link('catalog/option', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'] . $url, 'SSL'));
    }

    $this->getForm();
}

public function delete() {
    $this->language->load('catalog/option');

    $this->document->setTitle($this->language->get('heading_title'));

    $this->load->model('catalog/option');

    if (isset($this->request->post['selected']) && $this->validateDelete()) {
        foreach ($this->request->post['selected'] as $option_id) {
            $this->model_catalog_option->deleteOption($option_id);
        }

        $this->session->data['success'] = $this->language->get('text_success');

        $url = '';

        if (isset($this->request->get['sort'])) {
            $url .= '&sort=' . $this->request->get['sort'];
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['order'])) {
            $url .= '&order=' . $this->request->get['order'];
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['page'])) {
            $url .= '&page=' . $this->request->get['page'];
        }

        $this->response->redirect($this->url->link('catalog/option', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'] . $url, 'SSL'));
    }

    $this->getList();
}

protected function getList() {
    if (isset($this->request->get['sort'])) {
        $sort = $this->request->get['sort'];
    } else {
        $sort = 'od.name';
    }

    if (isset($this->request->get['order'])) {
        $order = $this->request->get['order'];
    } else {
        $order = 'ASC';
    }

    if (isset($this->request->get['page'])) {
        $page = $this->request->get['page'];
    } else {
        $page = 1;
    }

    $url = '';

    if (isset($this->request->get['sort'])) {
        $url .= '&sort=' . $this->request->get['sort'];
    }

    if (isset($this->request->get['order'])) {
        $url .= '&order=' . $this->request->get['order'];
    }

    if (isset($this->request->get['page'])) {
        $url .= '&page=' . $this->request->get['page'];
    }

    $data['breadcrumbs'] = array();

    $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
        'text' => $this->language->get('text_home'),
        'href' => $this->url->link('common/dashboard', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL')
    );

    $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
        'text' => $this->language->get('heading_title'),
        'href' => $this->url->link('catalog/option', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'] . $url, 'SSL')
    );

    $data['add'] = $this->url->link('catalog/option/add', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'] . $url, 'SSL');
    $data['delete'] = $this->url->link('catalog/option/delete', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'] . $url, 'SSL');

    $data['options'] = array();

    $filter_data = array(
        'sort'  => $sort,
        'order' => $order,
        'start' => ($page - 1) * $this->config->get('config_limit_admin'),
        'limit' => $this->config->get('config_limit_admin')
    );

    $option_total = $this->model_catalog_option->getTotalOptions();

    $results = $this->model_catalog_option->getOptions($filter_data);

    foreach ($results as $result) {
        $data['options'][] = array(
            'option_id'  => $result['option_id'],
            'name'       => $result['name'],
            'sort_order' => $result['sort_order'],
            'edit'       => $this->url->link('catalog/option/edit', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'] . '&option_id=' . $result['option_id'] . $url, 'SSL')
        );
    }

    $data['heading_title'] = $this->language->get('heading_title');

    $data['text_list'] = $this->language->get('text_list');
    $data['text_no_results'] = $this->language->get('text_no_results');
    $data['text_confirm'] = $this->language->get('text_confirm');

    $data['column_name'] = $this->language->get('column_name');
    $data['column_sort_order'] = $this->language->get('column_sort_order');
    $data['column_action'] = $this->language->get('column_action');

    $data['button_add'] = $this->language->get('button_add');
    $data['button_edit'] = $this->language->get('button_edit');
    $data['button_delete'] = $this->language->get('button_delete');

    if (isset($this->error['warning'])) {
        $data['error_warning'] = $this->error['warning'];
    } else {
        $data['error_warning'] = '';
    }

    if (isset($this->session->data['success'])) {
        $data['success'] = $this->session->data['success'];

        unset($this->session->data['success']);
    } else {
        $data['success'] = '';
    }

    if (isset($this->request->post['selected'])) {
        $data['selected'] = (array)$this->request->post['selected'];
    } else {
        $data['selected'] = array();
    }

    $url = '';

    if ($order == 'ASC') {
        $url .= '&order=DESC';
    } else {
        $url .= '&order=ASC';
    }

    if (isset($this->request->get['page'])) {
        $url .= '&page=' . $this->request->get['page'];
    }

    $data['sort_name'] = $this->url->link('catalog/option', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'] . '&sort=od.name' . $url, 'SSL');
    $data['sort_sort_order'] = $this->url->link('catalog/option', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'] . '&sort=o.sort_order' . $url, 'SSL');

    $url = '';

    if (isset($this->request->get['sort'])) {
        $url .= '&sort=' . $this->request->get['sort'];
    }

    if (isset($this->request->get['order'])) {
        $url .= '&order=' . $this->request->get['order'];
    }

    $pagination = new Pagination();
    $pagination->total = $option_total;
    $pagination->page = $page;
    $pagination->limit = $this->config->get('config_limit_admin');
    $pagination->url = $this->url->link('catalog/option', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'] . $url . '&page={page}', 'SSL');

    $data['pagination'] = $pagination->render();

    $data['results'] = sprintf($this->language->get('text_pagination'), ($option_total) ? (($page - 1) * $this->config->get('config_limit_admin')) + 1 : 0, ((($page - 1) * $this->config->get('config_limit_admin')) > ($option_total - $this->config->get('config_limit_admin'))) ? $option_total : ((($page - 1) * $this->config->get('config_limit_admin')) + $this->config->get('config_limit_admin')), $option_total, ceil($option_total / $this->config->get('config_limit_admin')));

    $data['sort'] = $sort;
    $data['order'] = $order;

    $data['header'] = $this->load->controller('common/header');
    $data['column_left'] = $this->load->controller('common/column_left');
    $data['footer'] = $this->load->controller('common/footer');

    $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('catalog/option_list.tpl', $data));
}

protected function getForm() {
    $data['heading_title'] = $this->language->get('heading_title');

    $data['text_form'] = !isset($this->request->get['option_id']) ? $this->language->get('text_add') : $this->language->get('text_edit');
    $data['text_choose'] = $this->language->get('text_choose');
    $data['text_select'] = $this->language->get('text_select');
    $data['text_radio'] = $this->language->get('text_radio');
    $data['text_checkbox'] = $this->language->get('text_checkbox');
    $data['text_checkbox_shildik'] = $this->language->get('text_checkbox_shildik');
    $data['text_image'] = $this->language->get('text_image');
    $data['text_input'] = $this->language->get('text_input');
    $data['text_text'] = $this->language->get('text_text');
    $data['text_textarea'] = $this->language->get('text_textarea');
    $data['text_file'] = $this->language->get('text_file');
    $data['text_date'] = $this->language->get('text_date');
    $data['text_datetime'] = $this->language->get('text_datetime');
    $data['text_time'] = $this->language->get('text_time');

    $data['entry_name'] = $this->language->get('entry_name');
    $data['entry_type'] = $this->language->get('entry_type');
    $data['entry_option_value'] = $this->language->get('entry_option_value');
    $data['entry_image'] = $this->language->get('entry_image');
    $data['entry_sort_order'] = $this->language->get('entry_sort_order');

    $data['button_save'] = $this->language->get('button_save');
    $data['button_cancel'] = $this->language->get('button_cancel');
    $data['button_option_value_add'] = $this->language->get('button_option_value_add');
    $data['button_remove'] = $this->language->get('button_remove');

    if (isset($this->error['warning'])) {
        $data['error_warning'] = $this->error['warning'];
    } else {
        $data['error_warning'] = '';
    }

    if (isset($this->error['name'])) {
        $data['error_name'] = $this->error['name'];
    } else {
        $data['error_name'] = array();
    }

    if (isset($this->error['option_value'])) {
        $data['error_option_value'] = $this->error['option_value'];
    } else {
        $data['error_option_value'] = array();
    }

    $url = '';

    if (isset($this->request->get['sort'])) {
        $url .= '&sort=' . $this->request->get['sort'];
    }

    if (isset($this->request->get['order'])) {
        $url .= '&order=' . $this->request->get['order'];
    }

    if (isset($this->request->get['page'])) {
        $url .= '&page=' . $this->request->get['page'];
    }

    $data['breadcrumbs'] = array();

    $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
        'text' => $this->language->get('text_home'),
        'href' => $this->url->link('common/dashboard', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL')
    );

    $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
        'text' => $this->language->get('heading_title'),
        'href' => $this->url->link('catalog/option', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'] . $url, 'SSL')
    );

    if (!isset($this->request->get['option_id'])) {
        $data['action'] = $this->url->link('catalog/option/add', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'] . $url, 'SSL');
    } else {
        $data['action'] = $this->url->link('catalog/option/edit', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'] . '&option_id=' . $this->request->get['option_id'] . $url, 'SSL');
    }

    $data['cancel'] = $this->url->link('catalog/option', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'] . $url, 'SSL');

    if (isset($this->request->get['option_id']) && ($this->request->server['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST')) {
        $option_info = $this->model_catalog_option->getOption($this->request->get['option_id']);
    }

    $data['token'] = $this->session->data['token'];

    $this->load->model('localisation/language');

    $data['languages'] = $this->model_localisation_language->getLanguages();

    if (isset($this->request->post['option_description'])) {
        $data['option_description'] = $this->request->post['option_description'];
    } elseif (isset($this->request->get['option_id'])) {
        $data['option_description'] = $this->model_catalog_option->getOptionDescriptions($this->request->get['option_id']);
    } else {
        $data['option_description'] = array();
    }

    if (isset($this->request->post['type'])) {
        $data['type'] = $this->request->post['type'];
    } elseif (!empty($option_info)) {
        $data['type'] = $option_info['type'];
    } else {
        $data['type'] = '';
    }

    if (isset($this->request->post['sort_order'])) {
        $data['sort_order'] = $this->request->post['sort_order'];
    } elseif (!empty($option_info)) {
        $data['sort_order'] = $option_info['sort_order'];
    } else {
        $data['sort_order'] = '';
    }

    if (isset($this->request->post['option_value'])) {
        $option_values = $this->request->post['option_value'];
    } elseif (isset($this->request->get['option_id'])) {
        $option_values = $this->model_catalog_option->getOptionValueDescriptions($this->request->get['option_id']);
    } else {
        $option_values = array();
    }

    $this->load->model('tool/image');

    $data['option_values'] = array();

    foreach ($option_values as $option_value) {
        if (is_file(DIR_IMAGE . $option_value['image'])) {
            $image = $option_value['image'];
            $thumb = $option_value['image'];
        } else {
            $image = '';
            $thumb = 'no_image.png';
        }

        $data['option_values'][] = array(
            'option_value_id'          => $option_value['option_value_id'],
            'option_value_description' => $option_value['option_value_description'],
            'image'                    => $image,
            'thumb'                    => $this->model_tool_image->resize($thumb, 100, 100),
            'sort_order'               => $option_value['sort_order']
        );
    }

    $data['placeholder'] = $this->model_tool_image->resize('no_image.png', 100, 100);

    $data['header'] = $this->load->controller('common/header');
    $data['column_left'] = $this->load->controller('common/column_left');
    $data['footer'] = $this->load->controller('common/footer');

    $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('catalog/option_form.tpl', $data));
}

protected function validateForm() {
    if (!$this->user->hasPermission('modify', 'catalog/option')) {
        $this->error['warning'] = $this->language->get('error_permission');
    }

    foreach ($this->request->post['option_description'] as $language_id => $value) {
        if ((utf8_strlen($value['name']) < 1) || (utf8_strlen($value['name']) > 128)) {
            $this->error['name'][$language_id] = $this->language->get('error_name');
        }
    }

    if (($this->request->post['type'] == 'select' || $this->request->post['type'] == 'radio' || $this->request->post['type'] == 'checkbox' || $this->request->post['type'] == 'checkbox_vors' || $this->request->post['type'] == 'checkbox_shildik' || $this->request->post['type'] == 'checkbox_clips') && !isset($this->request->post['option_value'])) {
        $this->error['warning'] = $this->language->get('error_type');
    }

    if (isset($this->request->post['option_value'])) {
        foreach ($this->request->post['option_value'] as $option_value_id => $option_value) {
            foreach ($option_value['option_value_description'] as $language_id => $option_value_description) {
                if ((utf8_strlen($option_value_description['name']) < 1) || (utf8_strlen($option_value_description['name']) > 128)) {
                    $this->error['option_value'][$option_value_id][$language_id] = $this->language->get('error_option_value');
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return !$this->error;
}

protected function validateDelete() {
    if (!$this->user->hasPermission('modify', 'catalog/option')) {
        $this->error['warning'] = $this->language->get('error_permission');
    }

    $this->load->model('catalog/product');

    foreach ($this->request->post['selected'] as $option_id) {
        $product_total = $this->model_catalog_product->getTotalProductsByOptionId($option_id);

        if ($product_total) {
            $this->error['warning'] = sprintf($this->language->get('error_product'), $product_total);
        }
    }

    return !$this->error;
}

public function autocomplete() {
    $json = array();

    if (isset($this->request->get['filter_name'])) {
        $this->language->load('catalog/option');

        $this->load->model('catalog/option');

        $this->load->model('tool/image');

        $filter_data = array(
            'filter_name' => $this->request->get['filter_name'],
            'start'       => 0,
            'limit'       => 5
        );

        $options = $this->model_catalog_option->getOptions($filter_data);

        foreach ($options as $option) {
            $option_value_data = array();

            if ($option['type'] == 'select' || $option['type'] == 'radio' || $option['type'] == 'checkbox' || $option['type'] == 'checkbox_vors' || $option['type'] == 'checkbox_shildik' || $option['type'] == 'checkbox_clips' || $option['type'] == 'image') {
                $option_values = $this->model_catalog_option->getOptionValues($option['option_id']);

                foreach ($option_values as $option_value) {
                    if (is_file(DIR_IMAGE . $option_value['image'])) {
                        $image = $this->model_tool_image->resize($option_value['image'], 50, 50);
                    } else {
                        $image = $this->model_tool_image->resize('no_image.png', 50, 50);
                    }

                    $option_value_data[] = array(
                        'option_value_id' => $option_value['option_value_id'],
                        'name'            => strip_tags(html_entity_decode($option_value['name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')),
                        'image'           => $image
                    );
                }

                $sort_order = array();

                foreach ($option_value_data as $key => $value) {
                    $sort_order[$key] = $value['name'];
                }

                array_multisort($sort_order, SORT_ASC, $option_value_data);
            }

            $type = '';

            if ($option['type'] == 'select' || $option['type'] == 'radio' || $option['type'] == 'checkbox' || $option['type'] == 'checkbox_vors' || $option['type'] == 'checkbox_shildik' || $option['type'] == 'checkbox_clips' || $option['type'] == 'image') {
                $type = $this->language->get('text_choose');
            }

            if ($option['type'] == 'text' || $option['type'] == 'textarea') {
                $type = $this->language->get('text_input');
            }

            if ($option['type'] == 'file') {
                $type = $this->language->get('text_file');
            }

            if ($option['type'] == 'date' || $option['type'] == 'datetime' || $option['type'] == 'time') {
                $type = $this->language->get('text_date');
            }

            $json[] = array(
                'option_id'    => $option['option_id'],
                'name'         => strip_tags(html_entity_decode($option['name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')),
                'category'     => $type,
                'type'         => $option['type'],
                'option_value' => $option_value_data
            );
        }
    }

    $sort_order = array();

    foreach ($json as $key => $value) {
        $sort_order[$key] = $value['name'];
    }

    array_multisort($sort_order, SORT_ASC, $json);

    $this->response->addHeader('Content-Type: application/json');
    $this->response->setOutput(json_encode($json));
}
```

I dont know why opencart developers didnt do this feature by default(((

Comment: Are these options limited to a single product? If you disable the "Red" option because you've run out of red socks, you'd run the risk of also disabling red shoes, if they use the same option. In OpenCart the option is managed on a Product->Option relationship. If your option was an add-on that was not necessarily product specific (e.g. a gift-box) then it may make sense to disable it completely.

Comment: Yes, I need to disable Red color option from all the products, but not delete it. Im thinking now to make some additional text field in option values and display this field in product css. For example in the field I type "none", and on product card css style I make .someclass {display: <?php echo $additional field ?>}  But I dont know how to do it

Comment: What's your level of experience with database queries?

Comment: I think low:( Trying google how to do it, but nothing